# How to restore damaged (mp3?) file

Tags: mp3, restore, forensics, hex-editor

I have been given a file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Fqr6Ipu2J8yKU_m3-EMzsVj7XeSYEdV/view?usp=sharing. Opening it from https://hexed.it/ shows that it is likely a mp3 file (based on the ID3 information at the end of the file). The task is to restore the file header such that we would be able to open it (presumably in a music player). Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

I noticed that the file header was empty bytes, so I tried to copy over starting bytes from a working mp3 file. Also tried moving the last few bytes with legible text to the start of the file. Neither of those worked.

Comment: the file requires access to be given to download it

Comment: Relating to off-site files is useless to SO. They may disappear. So include the essential parts of the link's files into the question to create a complete question.

Comment: As shown by the fact the file's not accessible. I *would* still find an original file useful since I don't have any broken mp3 files right now. I'd want to run the file against  https://mp3diags.sourceforge.net - its old but it might give you an idea what's broken

Comment: Updated the link, should be accessible now!

Comment: Hm, mp3diags isn't sure what it is- I ran it against the online version of trid https://mark0.net/onlinetrid.py and it thinks its a photoshop brush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP3 files **do not have** a mandatory header; they are just a raw series of MPEG audio frames, with each frame having its own 4-byte mini-header ([a](https://id3lib.sourceforge.net/id3/mp3frame.html), [b](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)). Everything else is extra. (Even ID3 tags and LAME headers – both being much later additions – are disguised as invalid frames that most players now know to ignore.)

Additionally, the frame format is self-synchronizing – you can cut it at any point, and a decoder will ignore the garbage half-frame at the beginning, looking for the sync bits `0xFFF` to find the start of the next frame. This means that you can literally throw any random piece of an MP3 file at a decoder and it should play; if it doesn't, then it is most likely not an MP3 file at all.

I would conclude that your file is not MP3; it's something else that uses the ID3 tagging format (rare but not unusual). More than that, the end bits of your file don't look *quite* like an ID3 tag – many of those 4-letter chunk identifiers do not start with 'T' as would be typical for ID3v2; they look to me more like what you'd find in a **chunked format** such as [AIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) or [WAV/RIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) (both of which indeed embed ID3 tags!), but not in MP3.

*(Well, yes, an ID3 tag itself is also a chunked format – but MP3 overall is not, is the point.)*

There are quite a few other tagged/chunked formats besides IFF and its AIFF/RIFF derivatives, e.g. PNG as well as ISO BMFF (which is used for MP4/HEIF/AVIF files) are similar in concept, but the specific chunk names used in your file – `LIST`, `INFO` – are distinctively RIFF, which is used for various Windows-related formats: .wav for audio, .avi for video, .ani for animated mouse cursors, etc. The `data` near the very beginning is most likely also a chunk tag.

Out of those RIFF sub-formats, the `IART` (artist), `ICRD` (date), `IGNR` (genre), `id3␣` (embedded ID3 tag) chunks would be typical of a WAV file. **What's missing is the toplevel `RIFF` chunk** (and perhaps part of the `fmt␣` chunk), which prevents players from recognizing the file.

Offset 0x10 does look like the full contents of the `fmt␣` chunk when compared to another .wav file, so the missing initial eight bytes should look like:

```
00000000  52 49 46 46 __ __ __ __  57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  |RIFF____WAVEfmt |
```

…with the empty part being the length of the toplevel chunk (or 0xFFFFFFFF to just indicate "the whole file"). The overall structure should be like this:

```
RIFF[WAVE]
 ├─fmt␣   (PCM S16LE)
 ├─data   (~Never gonna give you up~)
 ├─LIST[INFO]
 │  ├─IART = "GCTF"
 │  ├─ICRD
 │  └─IGNR = "Drum & Bass"
 └─id3␣   (embedded ID3, not RIFF-format)
    ├─TPE1 = "GCTF"
    ├─TDRC
    └─TCON = "Drum & Bass"
```

If you attempt to repair the header, use `fq` to inspect it (which also works nicely for actual MP3 files and other common formats):

```
$ fq . test.wav
$ fq .chunks[] test.wav
$ fq .chunks[2].chunks[] test.wav
```

[image]

Alternatively, since you do have the whole `data` chunk that contains the entirety of the PCM data (with a 4-byte length), it might be easier to extract that part only and try various raw PCM formats via brute force (there aren't that many combinations).

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed response -- not sure if I understood everything. So one way is for me to replace the first line with 52 49 46 46 __ __ __ __  57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 , what do I insert for the empty part? Not sure what do you mean by length of toplevel chunk. Another way is to brute force varius raw PCM formats? Does that just mean changing the file extension name such as adding .wav behind the filename, because I have tried that already.

Comment: 1) I've had luck inserting 0xFFFFFFFF in that field, since the actual file is larger than the maximum possible value anyway, and both `fq` and actual audio players [seem to accept this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie1js.png). 2) See the structure tree – each element has its own length field, and the 'RIFF' element is at the root. It's structured kind of like XML or HTML tags with `<html>` at the root, only binary instead of text.

Comment: 3) No, it means first copypasting the [raw audio data that follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nS9F.png) the `data` marker into a separate file, then opening it in audio editing software as a "raw" file – not .wav (that's raw+metadata), but an actual raw file with no headers, where the audio software will ask you to manually specify a "sample format" like '44100hz/stereo/S16LE'. In this case it's not necessary since your file does have the (almost) full header anyway, including the whole `fmt` chunk that describes the format.

Comment: (I don't know why I said "since the actual file is larger than the maximum possible value anyway" – it really isn't, as the file is under 1M and the maximum is 4G – but 0xFFFFFFFF will work either way.)